Functions that model polarising light filters
On a video about negative probability, the guy used an example involving polarising light filters. That automatically got me thinking about how to express them mathematically.
When you apply one filter, it still lets you see what's behind it, but less so. When you apply the second, what happens depends on the orientation. If the orientation is the same, nothing happens. If the orientation is perpendicular, the waves are reduced in two of two orthogonal directions, so no light gets through.
The first thing my mind went to was complex numbers, because their modulus-argument expression involves two perpendicular waves. So we could make
$$f(x)=\Re(x)$$ and $$g(x)=i\Im(x)$$
These satisfy $f\circ f=f$ and $g\circ g=g$ as well as $f\circ g=g\circ f=0$. What's more, $|f(x)|\leq|x|$ and $|g(x)|\leq|x|$, which kind of expresses how the image is brighter afore the filter is inserted.
This is a start, but only captures the parallel and perpendicular cases for the second filter. What about in between them? I thought we could define a function
$$h_{\alpha}(x)=\alpha \Re(x)+(1-\alpha) i \Im(x)$$ for $\alpha\in\left[0,1\right]$
But we want to capture the angle between them, so we can instead use
$$h_{\cos(\theta)}(x)=\cos(\theta)\Re(x)+\operatorname{versin}(\theta) i \Im(x)$$ where $\operatorname{versin}(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\equiv1$ and $\theta\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ to keep $\alpha=\cos(\theta)$ in the same original domain.
Then I realised it simplifies further. Why $\cos(\theta)$? I figured that, since the world has no inherent orientation, we can choose the orientation of the first one. W.L.O.G., the first filter is $f(x)$. Then, if they're parallel, $\theta=0$ and $h_{\cos(0)}\circ f=f$, and if they're perpendicular $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $h_{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\circ f=0$. If they're in between, $h_{\cos(\theta)}\circ f=\cos(\theta) f$
So is this the proper way one should mathematically model this situation? Treat the first filter as $\Re(x)$ and the second as multiplying by $\cos(\theta)$? It feels somewhat fitting, as it now depends directly upon the angle between them, but extracting the real part still feels a bit unintuitive. Is there a space and a function that befits this better, whether the dimensions are two or infinite?
